# Shutting down python internally?

Tags: python

I did GCSE Computing so I have decent understanding of python, I am now doing A levels one of my A levels being Physics. My friend and I are building a code that complies of many smaller code that all figure out equations for us. I am currently building the frame for the code and I was wondering if there is a code that shuts python down completely not just the code that I am currently running? I have looked around but haven't been able to find one that does.

Thanks in advace.

*edit*

This is my code;

```
import sys
print ("Welcome to Adam and Emrys' master code for figguring out all of your physic equations")

masterloop = 1
while masterloop == 1:
masterloop == 0

typeq = input("Now out of; waves, photoeletric effect    , which are you dealing with? ")

if typeq == "wave" or typeq == "waves" or typeq == "Wave" or typeq == "Waves":
    h=6.63*10**-34
    c=3*10**8
    loop=1
    print("(HC)/E=lambda and (HC)/lambda=E")
    while loop==1:
        loop=0
        Achoice=input("Are you working out the wave length or the energy?:")


        if Achoice=="energy"or Achoice=="Energy"or Achoice=="E":
            lambdA=float(input("What is the wavelength in meters?:"))
            e=(h*c)/lambdA
            print("HC over Lambda where the wavelength is",lambdA,"gives an energy of",e,"joules.")
        elif Achoice=="Wavelength"or Achoice=="wavelength"or Achoice=="W":
            e=float(input("What is the energy in joules?:"))
            lambdA=(h*c)/e
            print("HC over E where E is",e,"Gives wavelength as",lambdA)
        else:
            print("This is not an acceptable answer, please try again.")
            loop=1

elif typeq == "photoeletric effect" or typeq == "Photoeletric effect":
    h = 6.63*10**-34
    c = 3*10*8
    loop = 1
    print ("hf = Thi + Ekmax so Ekmax = hf - Thi, Thi being the Work function")

    while loop == 1:
        loop = 0
        freq = float(input("What is the frequancey of the light? "))
        Thi = float(input("What is the work funcion for your metal? ")
        answer = (( h * freq ) - Thi)

else:
    print("Thats not an exepted answer sorry please try again")

repet = input("Do you want to as another question or do you want to end the program? ")
loop = 1

while loop == 1:
    if repet == "another" or repet == "Another":
        loop = 0
        masterloop = 1

    elif repet == "end" or repet == "End":
        loop = 0
        sys.exit()
```

Sorry everyone for wasting your time I didn't realise that sys.exit() didn't end it in shell I'm so sorry thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Have you tried [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit)?

Comment: Yes but that only ends the running code I was more wondering if there was anything that completely shuts down python

Comment: What do you mean by "shuts python down completely not just the code that I am currently running". Do you mean every python process?

Comment: What do you mean by running code? Can you provide an example where it does not work?

Comment: So I have run my code using sys.exit() giving me;
Welcome to Adam and Emrys' master code for figguring out all of your physic equations
Now out of; waves, photoeletric effect    , which are you dealing with? waves
(HC)/E=lambda and (HC)/lambda=E
Are you working out the wave length or the energy?:energy
What is the wavelength in meters?:0.352464223
HC over Lambda where the wavelength is 0.352464223 gives an energy of 5.643125940756829e-25 joules.
Do you want to as another question or do you want to end the program? end
>>> 

but I would like to fully shut down python if possible

Comment: It sounds like you are running your code from with something like Idle or some other IDE. No, your code has no business shutting down the program that ran it.

Comment: As per the comment above, can you tell us how you run/start your program?

Comment: Well you could do `subprocess.call('taskkill /F /T /IM "python*"')` Which would kill all processes whose names begin with `"python"`. Wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: It shutting the code down is fine it makes sense however I'd also like to shut down python or is it just not possible. Its not essential more an aesthetics thing

Comment: You may be misunderstanding exactly what it means to "shut down python".

Comment: I probably am, sorry, what is meant? I am meaning it in the sense of the window being closed down, if that makes an sense?

Comment: @EmrysLawton What window? Python doesn't have any concept of the "window" it's run in unless you create that window yourself using tkinter or some other similar library. If you're talking about an IDE (like IDLE), or a command prompt or terminal window, then no, there's no way for your Python program to close it. (Edit: apart from possible hackish ways of finding the enclosing process and telling the OS to kill it, but that's not a good idea.)